# Contour integral calculation 2

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

> Show that 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x+a} \; dx= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^2+a^2}\;dx \quad (a>0)
> \end{align*}

My Attempt: I showed that

\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x+a} \; dx &= \frac{1}{2ai} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{x+a} \;dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2ai}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{x-ia} \; dx 
\end{align*}
by using contur integral. Also, 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^2+a^2}\;dx =\frac{1}{2ai}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x-ai}-\frac{e^{-x}}{x+ai} \; dx
\end{align*}
Thus, It suffices to show that 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{x-ia} \; dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x+ai} \; dx 
\end{align*}

But, I stuck how to prove that....

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with the first integral within your first line: according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(infinity)+e%5E(x)%2F(x-i*a)) it does not converge.

Comment: If $a>0$, there are values of $\int \frac{\sin x} {x+a} dx , \int \frac{ e^{-x}}{x^2+a^2}$

Comment: Rethink the last equality in your first step - when you went from $ix$ to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only perform contour integration around infinite region if the part that circles around infinity vanishes. Otherwise you get divergent integrals (your integrals that include $e^{+x}$ cannot possibly converge). Your integral:

$$\frac1{2ai}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{x+a}dx$$
consists of two integrands. The first term $e^{ix}$ will converge to zero on the upper half-plane. For it, you can integrate $0+0i\to \infty+0i \to 0+\infty i \to 0+0i$. You also know you did not encircle any poles, so you can write:
$$\frac1{2ai}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x+a}dx+\frac1{2ai}\int_{\infty i}^0 \frac{e^{ix}}{x+a}dx=0$$
substitute $x=0+it$, reverse integration boundaries and carry to the right side of the equals sign:
$$\frac1{2ai}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x+a}dx=\frac1{2a}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{it+a} dt$$

The second integral converges in the *lower* half-plane, so you must integrate $0+0i\to \infty + 0i \to 0-\infty i \to 0+0i$ to get something that includes your integral *and* has a zero contribution on the quarter-circle infinite arc from real to imaginary infinity.
$$\frac1{2ai}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ix}}{x+a}dx+\frac1{2ai}\int_{-\infty i}^0 \frac{e^{-ix}}{x+a}dx=0$$
Now, use $x=0-it$ and you get:
$$\frac1{2ai}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ix}}{x+a}dx=-\frac1{2a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{-it+a}dt$$

Now (once you are sure they both individually converge), you can put them together (there is a minus between the terms):
$$\frac1{2ai}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{x+a}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left(\frac{1}{it+a}+\frac{1}{-it+a}\right)dt$$
You can do the final recombination of the fractions yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The Laplace transform is a self-adjoint operator, i.e.
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x)\cdot(\mathcal{L} g)(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} g(x)\cdot(\mathcal{L} f)(x)\,dx$$
by Fubini's theorem. For any $a>0$ we have
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin x)(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+1},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x+a}\right)=e^{-ax} $$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{a(x+a)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}}{a(x^2+1)}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto t/a}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2+a^2}\,dt$$
QED.

Comment: Very short and elegant way of using a nuke to kill a fly.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x + a} \,\dd x =
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over x^{2} + a^{2}}\,\dd x:\
> {\LARGE ?} \qquad \pars{~a > 0~}}$.

With $\ds{R > a > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left. {1 \over a}\int_{0}^{R}{\sin\pars{x} \over x + a} \,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0}} =
{1 \over a}\,\Im\int_{0}^{R}{\expo{\ic x} \over x + a} \,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over a}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\exp\pars{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta}} \over R\expo{\ic\theta} + a} \,R\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta -
{1 \over a}\,\Im\int_{R}^{0}{\expo{\ic\pars{\ic y}} \over
\ic y + a}\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{R \over a}\,\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\exp\pars{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta}} \over R\expo{\ic\theta} + a} \,\expo{\ic\theta}\,\dd\theta +
{1 \over a}\,\Re\int_{0}^{R}{a - \ic y \over
y^{2} + a^{2}}\,\expo{-y}\dd y\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Note that

\begin{align}
& 0 < \verts{-\,{R \over a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\exp\pars{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta}} \over R\expo{\ic\theta} + a} \,\expo{\ic\theta}\,\dd\theta}
\\[5mm] < &\
{R \over a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\exp\pars{-R\sin\pars{\theta}} \over R} \,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] < &
{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\exp\pars{-2R\theta/\pi}\,\dd\theta =
{1 \over a}\,{\expo{-R} - 1 \over 2R/\pi}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\, 0
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}

$$
\implies
\bbx{\left.{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x + a} \,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over x^{2} + a^{2}}\,\dd x}
$$